# Tensorflow: Inputting encapsulated data batch through single placeholder

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensor

I am generally struggling with indexing tensors in tensorflow.
I have image data and additional scalar data. I can only use a single placeholder to input all the data to a Neural Network.

The images (img) are numpy arrays with shape `(84,84,3)` and I have data a with shape `(2)` and b with shape `(1)`.

Now I create a single sample

```
sample = np.reshape(np.array([img,a,b]),(3,1)) #shape (3,1)
```

The placeholder is

```
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None] + list(sample.shape))
```

Now when TF reads a batch of samples I would like to retrieve the batch of images, the batch of a, and the batch of b, because they need to be input in different locations in the Neural Network.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import layers
import numpy as np

#Numpy
img = np.random.rand(84,84,3)
a = np.random.rand(2)
b = np.random.rand(1)
sample = np.reshape(np.array([img,a,b]),(3,1)) #shape (3,1)
batch = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(sample,axis=0),32,axis=0) #shape (32,3,1)

#TF
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None] + list(sample.shape))

#TODO:
tf_img = tf.#get image batch from input
tf_a = tf.#get a batch from input
tf_b = tf.#get b batch from input

out = layers.convolution2d(tf_img,num_outputs=64,kernel_size=8,stride=2,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
out = layers.flatten(out)
out = tf.concat([out,tf_a,tf_b])
out = layers.fully_connected(out,10,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    _ = sess.run(out,feed_dict={input:batch})
```

How can I extract the individual parts of the input from a tensor with shape `(?,3,1)`, use the image data to create an embedding and concatenate the other two parts to that output enbedding.

Is there a better way to input the data? My only constraint is that it has to be a single placeholder.

Comment: Please clarify why you are restricted to a single placeholder! If all dimensions of your input data are known, you can wrap each sample into a single tensor of shape `(None, 84*84*3+2+1)` and use [slicing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) and [reshaping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) inside the graph.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am working with a large code template and I want to change as little as possible as it is quite convoluted (and it assumes a single image input). also I was wondering whether it is possible. Could you provide a larger example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example for my comment above:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

im_height = 84
im_width = 84
im_channels = 3
a_len = 2
b_len = 1

np_img = np.random.rand(im_height, im_width, im_channels)
np_a = np.random.rand(a_len)
np_b = np.random.rand(b_len)

# flatten the input and concatenate to a single 1D numpy array
np_sample = np.concatenate((np_img.reshape(-1), np_a.reshape(-1), np_b.reshape(-1)), axis=0)
# construct a pseudo batch
np_batch = np.repeat(np_sample[np.newaxis, :], 32, axis=0)

tf_batch = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, im_height*im_width*im_channels + a_len + b_len), dtype=tf.float32)

img_stop = im_height*im_width*im_channels
a_stop = img_stop+a_len

# you could also use tf.slice(...) here
tf_img = tf.reshape(tf_batch[:, 0:img_stop], (-1, im_height, im_width, im_channels))
tf_a = tf.reshape(tf_batch[:, img_stop:a_stop], (-1, a_len))
tf_b = tf.reshape(tf_batch[:, a_stop:], (-1, b_len))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    fetch_dict = {'img': tf_img, 'a': tf_a, 'b': tf_b}
    feed_dict = {tf_batch: np_batch}
    res = sess.run(fetch_dict, feed_dict=feed_dict)

assert(np.isclose(res['img'][0, ...], np_img).all())
assert(np.isclose(res['a'][0, :], np_a).all())
assert(np.isclose(res['b'][0, :], np_b).all())
```

However, this is at least as invasive as adding appropriate placeholders to the code. Additionally, it's much less readable, in my opinion.